# How to handle CXF unmarshalling errors in Mule Exception-Strategy

Tags: xml, soap, cxf, mule, mule-studio

I am new to Mule,... I have a webservice that has a following request :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:insertDataRequest>
         <v1:Id>6</v1:Id>
         <v1:Name>abc</v1:Name>
         <v1:Age>4</v1:Age>
         <v1:Designation>SE</v1:Designation>
      </v1:insertDataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My mule flow is somewhat likethe following :-

```
  <flow name="MuleDbInsertFlow1" doc:name="MuleDbInsertFlow1">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.test.services.v1.GetCalculation" doc:name="SOAP"/>
            <component class="com.test.services.v1.GetCalculationImpl" doc:name="Java"/>

 <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">

   <set-payload value="Error occoured!!!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

 </catch-exception-strategy>


</flow>
```

Now my question is here in the SOAP request the ID and AGE attributes are integer and if I put any string value like  `<v1:Id>aaaa</v1:Id>` it throws Fault like **org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Not a number** which is quite natural ... now how can I handle this `Unmarshalling error` and send custom message as response ... I tried by using catch exception block in Mule but I am unable to handle this **CXF unmarshalling error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one approach would be to use Interceptors with CXF Jaxws service.

This following link gives more detials of the CXF module in Mule and reference to Interceptors.

```
<cxf:jaxws-service .... ....>
  <cxf:inInterceptors>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:inInterceptors>
  <cxf:outInterceptors>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:jaxws-service>
```

Use Fault Interceptors to take control of the error processing.

[Mule CXF Module Reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/CXF+Module+Configuration+Reference)

Comment: Hi.. Thankyou for your response .. could you pls define elaborately how to handle this exception So that I can send custom message at response .. I have implemented <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/> but was unable to handle the exception .. pls define the next step need to do to handle the exception as I am very new in Mule

Comment: I provided LoggindInInterceptors as an emaple of showing the configuration of interceptors in cxf mule.  The Logging interceptors should be replaced with the Fault Interceptors to catch the error.